# ASP.Net - get querystring of page that has been redirected to

Tags: asp.net, http, oauth, request

The follwing code:

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/sandbox/htmlpage1.htm");

 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

 string url = ((HttpWebResponse)response).ResponseUri.ToString();
```

is requesting htmlpage1.html which in turn redirects to another page (otherpage.htm?qs=data). How can I get the querystring from the "other page" that htmlpage1.htm redirects to programatically. This is for LinkedIn OAuth2 routine from a winforms app. I need url variable to give me the querystring of otherpage.htm not htmlpage1.htm. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net we can get the query string by using

c# : Request.QueryString[""] . Say in your case it might be

Request.QueryString["qs"].

Comment: Thanks but not what I'm asking. This is a windows form application not browser based.